# React Bootstrap select option not showing

Tags: reactjs, forms, react-bootstrap

I couldn't get my Occupation field to work as a select option. What am I missing?

```
import { Row, Col, Form } from 'react-bootstrap';
import FloatingLabel from "react-bootstrap-floating-label";

<Row className="g-2 mb-5">
                    <Col md style={{marginRight: "50px"}}>
                        <FloatingLabel controlId="floatingInputGrid" label="Name">
                        <Form.Control type="text" placeholder="Name" />
                        </FloatingLabel>
                    </Col>
                    <Col md>
                        <FloatingLabel controlId="floatingSelectGrid" label="Occupation">
                            <Form.Select aria-label="Select">
                                <option>Open this select menu</option>
                                <option value="1">One</option>
                                <option value="2">Two</option>
                                <option value="3">Three</option>
                            </Form.Select>
                        </FloatingLabel>
                    </Col>
</Row>
```

[image: form]

Comment: please come with a working snippet, if you have a snippet that shows your problem clearly, it will solve your problem much faster compare to come without a snippet, in example, you can create a snippet from code sandbox

Answer (score 0):

react-bootstrap-floating-label does not provide any support/functionality for prop children such as Form.Control. Consider submitting an issue with the feature request